# dismissViewControllerAnimated not working

Tags: ios, ios6

I am using Storyboard with IOS6. I am trying to go back to the previous viewcontroller but it is not working.

I customized my backbutton here.

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 45,35);
[btnBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:15]];
btnBack.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
btnBack.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
[btnBack setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorFbBlue]];
btnBack.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorFbBlue].CGColor;
[btnBack setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_On_Btn_Back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];

-(void)Click_On_Btn_Back{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

This is how i push segue from previous view controller.

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFbShare"]){
    FbShareViewController *fbVC=[segue destinationViewController];
    fbVC.imageUrl=self.product.ImageUrl;

}
```

Comment: Are you presenting the `viewController` as a modal? Are you using a `navigationCotroller`?

Comment: not modal. It is just a push. I am using navigationcontroller.

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPush_Pop&ei=2pMCUvOwAYycigK49oHICQ&usg=AFQjCNFho3fVIKghJ-sSR_CAEVnpdpl3nA&sig2=IQvby_OKymbQKpz1pIwUPQ&bvm=bv.50310824,d.cGE

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Going to previous UIViewController when using a UINavigationController:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Put that line of code in your `Click_On_Btn_Back` method

Answer (score 4):

When using a Navigation Controller and `push` you need to remove the view by using:

```
- (void)Click_On_Btn_Back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also `Click_On_Btn_Back` is not general iOS naming convention. You should use something more like: `clickOnBtnBack` ([CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)).